# fluent nhibernate save children in parent's table

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have Ienumerable with ints and I wish to same this list as it is in parent's table.

For example if these are my Ienumerables:

```
list1 = {1, 2, 3 ,5}
list2= {2, 3, 4, 8}
list3 = {4 ,3,5 2}
```

I want nhibernate to create a table like:

```
parent= | id , item1, item2, item3, item4 |
        | 1,   1,     2,      3,     5  |
        | 2,   2,     3,      4,     8  |
        | 3,   4,     3,      5,     2  |
```

I've tried to use the following mapping:

```
Id(x => x.Id);
//Component(x => x.Cards, m =>  
  m.HasMany()).KeyColumn("cardId").Access.Field());;
  HasMany(x => x.Cards)
    //.KeyColumn("CardIdss").Table("Cardss")
    .Component(y =>
    {
        y.Map(z => z.CardId);
    });
```

But it creates another table, and this is not my intent.
Any advices?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your domain model classes?

Comment: Basically I want to map Ienumerable<int> (cards) as a single element into a table which represents CardDeck. So I won't create another table.

Comment: But IEnumerable does nor limited by 4 items. May be better to wrap it to class with 4 properties?